# Creating a linked list and a few methods from scratch

Tags: linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list and a few methods however I get a runtime error when I try to run it.

class MyLinkedList {

```
public class Node{
    
    int val;
    Node next;
    
    public Node(int x){
        this.val = x;                      
    }
}
    private Node head;
    private int size;
/** Initialize your data structure here. */
public MyLinkedList() {
    
}

/** Get the value of the index-th node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1. */
public int get(int index) {
    
    if(index >= size) return -1;
    
    Node current = head;
    int position = 0;
    while(position < index){
        current = current.next;
        position++;
    }
    return current.val;
}

/** Add a node of value val before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list. */
public void addAtHead(int val) {
   
   Node nody = new Node(val);
    nody.next = head;
    size++;
}

/** Append a node of value val to the last element of the linked list. */
public void addAtTail(int val) {
    
   Node current = head;
    
    while(current.next != null){
        current = current.next;
    }
    current.next = new Node(val);
    size++;
    

}

/** Add a node of value val before the index-th node in the linked list. If index equals to the length of linked list, the node will be appended to the end of linked list. If index is greater than the length, the node will not be inserted. */
public void addAtIndex(int index, int val) {
    
    if(index > size) return;
        
    if(index == size){
        addAtTail(val);
    }
    if(index == 0){
        addAtHead(val);
    }
    int position = 0;
    
    Node current = head;
    Node nody = new Node(val);
    while(position < index-1){
        current = current.next;
        position++;
    }
    nody.next = current.next;
    current.next = nody;
    size++;
    
}

/** Delete the index-th node in the linked list, if the index is valid. */
public void deleteAtIndex(int index) {
    
    if(index >= size){
        return;
    }
    if(index == 0){
        head = head.next;
    }
    
    Node current = head;
    int position = 0;
    while(position< index-1){
        current = current.next;
        position++;
    }
    current.next = current.next.next;
    size--;
    
    
}
```

}

/**

- Your MyLinkedList object will be instantiated and called as such:
- MyLinkedList obj = new MyLinkedList();
- int param_1 = obj.get(index);
- obj.addAtHead(val);
- obj.addAtTail(val);
- obj.addAtIndex(index,val);
- obj.deleteAtIndex(index);
  */

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace you get when you run the program.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of `Node` you are assigning the field `val` to itself (null), instead of assigning the constructor parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I assigned a value to val, but there is still a run time error.